# Finding the convergence of $\left\{\int_{0}^{n}\arctan(x)e^{-x}dx\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\left\{\int_{0}^{n}\arctan(x)e^{-x}dx\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$$

My attempt just involves taking the limit of the sequence:

$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\arctan(x)e^{-x}dx$$
$$u=\arctan(x)\to du=\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$dv=e^{-x}dx\to v=-e^{-x}$$

$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-\arctan(x)e^{-x}\Big|_0^n-\int_{0}^{n}\frac{-e^{-x}}{x^2+1}dx)$$

This attempt, however, just leads to a recursion that ends up with $I=I$ which isn't helpful. Any hints?

Comment: Is your goal to calculate the limit or to determine whether the limit exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integrand is nonnegative on $\mathbb{R}$, we have that that the sequence is increasing.

Also, the fact that $\arctan x \le \pi/2$ for all $x \ge 0$ implies that

$$\int_0^n \arctan(x) e^{-x} \, dx \le \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^n e^{-x}\, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} (1 - e^{-n}) \le \frac{\pi}{2} < \infty.$$

So the sequence is increasing and bounded above, hence convergent.

---

If you want the actual limit, that's a good deal more complicated. The friendly neighborhood [CAS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-x)+arctan(x)+from+0+to+inf) says that the limit is

$$\text{Ci}(1) \sin(1) - \text{Si}(1) \cos(1) + \frac 1 2 \pi \cos(1) \approx 0.62.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\arctan x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$.  So

$$  \int_0^\infty \arctan(x) \mathrm{e}^{-x} \,\mathrm{d} x < \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \,\mathrm{d} x =  \frac{\pi}{2}(-0 - - 1) = \frac{\pi}{2}  $$

Also, $\arctan(x) > 0$ and $\mathrm{e}^{-x} > 0$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$, so your sequence is (strictly) monotonically increasing and (upper) bounded...